# Question on equality with the log

Tags: inequality

Let us consider the equation :

$$\displaystyle n^{\frac{1}{\alpha\log n}} = 1$$

As $n$ approaches to infinity, what are the values of $\alpha$ such that above inequality hold?

Comment: I cannot see an *inequality* in your question.

Comment: It still makes no sense. Are you asking for which values of $\alpha$ the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{\alpha\log n}}$ exists, and is equal to one?

Comment: @Martin R Yes that is what I am asking

Comment: Then I suggest to update (and tag) the question accordingly. Don't forget to add your thoughts on the problem. How do you calculate $ n^{\frac{1}{\alpha\log n}}$, and where are you stuck in calculating the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the your logarithm is the natural logarithm we have  $n^{\frac 1{\alpha log n}}=e^{\frac 1{\alpha log n}\log n}=e^{1/\alpha}\neq 1$ for any $\alpha \neq 0$.

PS: Same thing  happens for logarithm to any base.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^{\frac{1}{\alpha \ln n}}= e^{\frac{1}{\alpha \ln n}\ln n}=e^{1/\alpha}=1$$
So no real finite solution for $\alpha$.

Comment: I just wonder how that is different from Kabo's answer.

Comment: The last line makes the difference, one has to say his.